# I can't 'Out-File' my whole loop just one line

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I created a random password generator, I need to Out-File all 10 outputs into a .txt file

But what I have now only has 1 line of the output.

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++){
$caps = [char[]] "ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXY"
$lows = [char[]] "abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxy" 
$nums = [char[]] "2346789"
$spl = [char[]] "!@#$%^&*?+"

$first = $lows | Get-Random -count 1;
$second = $caps | Get-Random -count 1;
$third = $nums | Get-Random -count 1;
$forth = $lows | Get-Random -count 1;
$fifth = $spl | Get-Random -count 1;
$sixth = $caps | Get-Random -count 1;

$pwd = [string](@($first) + @($second) + @($third) + @($forth) + @($fifth) + @($sixth))
Write-Host $pwd

Out-File .\Documents\L8_userpasswords.txt -InputObject $pwd

}
```

When I open the .txt I just see 1 line of the output instead of 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `Out-File` clobbers (overwrites) at the specified path if it exists. If the file doesn't exist prior script execution, use `-Append` to append to the file:

```
Out-File .\Documents\L8_userpasswords.txt -InputObject $pwd -Append
```

Note that this will append to the file each time the script is run. If you want the file to be recreated each time, check existence and delete it before entering the `for` loop:

```
$file = ".\L8_userpasswords.txt"
if (Test-Path -Path $file -PathType Leaf) {
    Remove-Item $file
}
for ($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++){
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `-Append` parameter for the `Out-File` cmdlet, because by default it will overwrite the specified file.

```
Out-File .\Documents\L8_userpasswords.txt -InputObject $pwd -Append;
```